# How to format a curl command for a special task?

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-script, curl, gnome-shell

There is a search page in a form `http://example.com/search.php` and it sends a search query via POST request. I want to fetch this request via curl command line tool to inspect a POST request.

The HTML form looks like this:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="search" size=20><br>
   SZ<input type="checkbox" checked name="sz">
   NZ<input type="checkbox" checked name="nz">
   <input type="submit" name="search_term" value="search" >
</form>
```

How should my `curl` command look like?

Comment: Curl is an HTTP client - it makes requests (aka fetching resources). It can't intercept a POST from another client, like your browser, which is what it sounds like you want to do. Or did you mean you want to make this POST request with curl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example, to send a search of "foo" with `sz` checked and `nz` unchecked:

```
curl -d "search_term=search&search=foo&sz=on&nz=off" http://example.com/search.php
```